# Use JsonResponse variable from Django in Html via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, promise

I am returning JsonResponse with the required hash from Django view on a ajax call.

How to use the Json object inside html via {{}} (jinja templating). Below is my ajax call:

```
$(function () {
        $('#getData').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Report",
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    'date1': $('#d1').val(),
                    'date2': $('#d2').val(),

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                    // How to pass the data here to use it in html
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

My sample html :

```
<div id="maindiv" class="col col-5 col-sm-10" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <h3> Showing Results for {{info.fromDate}} to {{info.toDate}}</h3>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="summary">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card mx-auto">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <p style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;padding: 20px;" class="card-text">
                            <h1><b><span style="font-size:80px;">{{info.total}}</span></b></h1>
                            <h6> Total  </h6>                                
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card" id='chart1' style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <script>
                            Info = {{ info.marks| safe }}
                            createpiechart("marks", 'chart1', Info); <!-- This creates an amchart -->
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is just a sample. I have many more charts and processing for which I used the jsonresponse variable via {{}} inside html. What is the correct way to get the data from ajax to html?

Initially I used render to return response to html. But I see that the data I capture in ajax has the entire html replaced with the {{}} variable's value

```
 return render(request=request, template_name='home/home.html', context={"info": InfoArray})
```

How to use the hash/context I pass from Django view inside html via a ajax ?

App\home.urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
#path('', views.index, name = "index"),
path('', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
]
```

App\urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('Report/', include('home.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: is your ajax call inside the template ?

Comment: yes Its inside my template

Comment: in your view you have to add `return JsonResponse({'context':'InfoArray'})` instead `render`

Comment: I used return JsonResponse({"info": InfoArray}) It dnt work. As in my question is how to use the {{info}} in html if i use ajax?

Comment: After the page has been rendered, if you want to change some text, then you can do that with JS. Provide a `id` to `<h3>` and change it with JS. `$('h3#some_id').text(data.text);`.